# Meteor Collection and Security

Tags: meteor

I am curious if I'm setting up the allow statement on this collection correctly. I'm using [aldeed:autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) and [aldeed:collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2).

Below is the snapshot of a issue-collection.js from a toy project.

Is this the proper way to set up allow checks? Do these run on both client (for minimongo) and server? Specifically, on most `update` calls, is `return !!userId && (doc.userId == userId);` enough to ensure the user is logged in AND the logged in user is the owner of the document?

**Clarification and actual question**: Do the `allow` and `deny` methods run on ***BOTH*** server and client? Or do they run only on the client?

Issues = new Mongo.Collection("issues");

```
if (Meteor.isClient){
  Meteor.subscribe("issues");
}

if(Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.publish('issues', function () {
    return Issues.find({}, {limit: ServerSettings.maxSubscribe});
  });
}


Issues.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({


  issue: {
    type: String,
    label: "Describe the issue you noticed",
    max:256
  }   

}));


//SECURITY - Allow Callbacks for posting

Issues.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {


    /* Throw in some defaults. */
    doc.userId = userId;
    doc.sumbitDate = new Date();
    doc.date = new Date();


    // only allow posting if you are logged in
    return !! userId;
  },
  update: function(userId, doc) {

    // only allow updating if you are logged in
    return !!userId && (doc.userId == userId);
  },
  remove: function(userID, doc) {
    //only allow deleting if you are owner
    return doc.submittedById === Meteor.userId();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, allow/deny comes from the client. And you can't trust anything that comes from the client (userId, date, etc).
What you want to do is call a `Meteor.method` from the client & `_.extend` the document with trustworthy data from the server.

As an example, rewrite that code in the browser console & change the value for the userId.

Check out Discover Meteor blog to learn more (it's probably the best source for learning basic patterns) https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog.

Comment: It was my understanding that the allow/deny methods ran on BOTH. That is an entry is made on the client side (even if they mess with JS code) to minimongo, but the server-side allow/deny would still block the insert(). Am I under the wrong assumption?

Comment: if it blocked the insert(), nothing would ever get into the database, right? Your code is explicitly allowing an insert, but it has no idea if the `userId` that is coming from the local collection was modified by the client.

Comment: I believe that the allow/deny methods do run on the server.  And the userId parameter can be relied upon.  See, e.g.,[ https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/meteor-and-security/].  This code requires a userId and forces the doc.userId.  So this code would be fine, I think.

Comment: Instead of trusting someone on the internet, check for yourself. Proving it is easy. Open up the console, create a `doc` object with a phony `userId` and call insert. See what happens.

Comment: It runs on the server. I added a console.log(doc) to the insert function. My terminal spat out the document. Browser console remained blank. That said much more research for me still remains.